# using TextEditingController observable text never change inside init onInit ever()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX. I need once the user type a letter I get this letter to associate it to an object. But the issues is when I use **ever function** inside **onInit fuction** inside the controller, there is no change happen. so the **even function** never implemented.

**The Controller Class Code Is:**

```
class RegistrationController extends GetxController {
  // Email
  late Rx<TextEditingController> emailEditionController;
  Rx<Email>? email;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    emailEditionController = TextEditingController().obs;
    ever(
      emailEditionController,
      (_) {
        print("\n checked \n");
        return email = Email(email: emailEditionController.value.text).obs;
      },
    );
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your motive actually?

Comment: `ever(
      emailEditionController,
      (_) {
        print("\n checked \n");
        return email = Email(email: emailEditionController.value.text).obs;
      },
    );` does not work when the controller changes. @Diwyansh

Comment: So you want to get the value entered in TextEditingContorller?

Comment: yeah, every time the user enter a new character, i receive it using ever(). @Diwyansh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onInit` fires when your `controller` gets `initialize` only for once that will not call again until you `force` it or `reinitialize` your `controller`. So put your functions outside of it and Try using code below :

```
class RegistrationController extends GetxController {
  // Email
  Rx<TextEditingController> emailEditionController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<Email>? email;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  ever(String val) {
    print("\n checked $val\n");
    return email?.value = Email(email: val); OR Email(email: emailEditionController.value.text);
  }
}
```

On TextField Side

```
TextFormField(
            controller: cont.emailEditionController.value,
            onChanged: (val){
              cont.ever(val);
            },
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add :

```
emailEditionController.value.text.obs
```

in your ever method.

Comment: i have tried so, but this error happens. `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RxInterface<Object?>'` @aminjamali

Comment: try emailEditionController.value.text.obs

Comment: i have tried it, no error occurs. but even function does not implemented.

Comment: is your text field inside a OBX?

Comment: yeah i use Obx. i created a print function to be printed, after implementation. so obx existence is not a big deal. i just need to implement the code of even.